# Setting Keyboard Shortcuts in Ubuntu 22.04 with gsettings (what's changed?)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, shortcut-keys, dconf, gsettings

It appears it should be relatively easy to set `Super+C` to launch my GNOME calculator in Ubuntu 22.04 with gsettings and the command line:

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom999/ name "'Launch Calculator'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom999/ binding "'<Super>c'"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom999/ command "'gnome-calculator'"
```

I issue the command, everything appears to work fine, then I press `Super+C` and nothing happens. **What did I do wrong?**

This will be part of a script, so I can't use any GUI solutions, although we could use the GUI (dconf, settings, etc.) for troubleshooting. In fact, that's what I've done and I can see the shortcut listed in my

```
dconf > org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > media-keys > custom-keybindings
```

however, it is missing from my

```
Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > View and Customize Shortcuts
```

that seems to be a symptom of why "nothing happens" when I press `Super+C`.